# Why don't we write axios.get(blabla) inside the render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why don't we write

```
axios
  .get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
  .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
```

inside the `render` method, do we have to put it in `componentWillMount`?

What would be wrong if we put it at the beginning of the `render` method?

I put it in the `render` and got the same result but the tutorial says that it should be in `componentWillMount`.

Comment: Well, you'd be submitting a request every time you rerendered, plus you should NEVER set state in render, or in a callback of an async function in render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the difference between the two would be in **how many times** do you want to make this request.

If you want the request to happen only the first time the component is mounted, you will use `ComponentWillMount` (preferable)

If you want the request to happen on every render (discouraged), then use the `render` method.

In your case, putting it in the `render` method would actually cause an infinite recursion because each request calls `setState` which will cause a re-render which will make the request which will call `setState` which will cause a re-render...

Not to mention the cost on performance as well as the network congestion from so many frequent requests.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    }
  }
  render() {
    // fake async action to act as a request
    setTimeout(() => {
      const { counter } = this.state;
      this.setState({
        counter: counter + 1
      })
    }, 500)
    return React.createElement('h3', null, this.state.counter)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Example),
  document.querySelector('#example')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<h2>Re-rendering forever</h2>
<div id="example"></div>
```